# SASS Compilation not working

Tags: css, sass

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 and Web Essentials 2013 update4. And embedded SASS. But suddenly the sass file stopped compiling new codes to css all imported files are working(there is a problem in mixins when included) but when I added new file including sass codes and imported it in main sass file it did not work and compiled, even I added the codes directly in the main sass file. Following is code in main sass file:

```
@import "Common/_public.scss";
@import "HomePage/_video.scss";
@import "HomePage/_home.scss";
@import "HomePage/_control.scss";
@import "HomePage/_monitor.scss";
@import "HomePage/_analyze.scss";
@import "HomePage/_accesibility.scss";
@import "HomePage/_capability.scss";
@import "HomePage/_portability.scss";
@import "HomePage/_contact-us.scss";
@import "HomePage/_footer.scss";
@import "Exrill/_exrill-side-menu.scss";
@import "Exrill/_home.scss";
@import "Exrill/_added-value.scss";
@import "Exrill/_dashboard.scss";
@import "Exrill/_pob.scss";
@import "Exrill/_footer.scss";
@import "Common/_animation.scss";
@import "More/_more-public.scss";
@import "More/_about-us.scss";
@import "More/_portfolio.scss";
@import "More/_job-opportunity.scss";
@import "Common/_font.scss";

.pricing-body{
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.pricing-list {
    width: 800px;
}

.pricing-list table {
    width: 100%;
}
```

all imported files are working now but the pure css code does not!!!

Comment: and what error are you getting ?

Comment: nothing. it just doesn't convert new sass codes into css. surprisingly when I add new sass file everything works well. It seems so weird.

Comment: I solved the problem. It's seems so silly but I renamed one of the files and did not modify in sass file and it didn't show me any error or warning.